# ¿Por que no funciona el método json.getString()?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, kotlin

Estoy usando la siguiente función para almacenar un json en una base de datos SQLite.

```
void addJson(JsonObject json) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PATIENT_ID,   json.getString("patientId"));
        values.put(KEY_ReadingType,json.getString("readingType"));
        values.put(KEY_DeviceMACId, json.getString("deviceMACId"));
        values.put(KEY_DeviceData , json.getString("deviceData"));
        values.put(KEY_DeviceType, json.getString("deviceType"));
        db.insert(TABLE_Demo , null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

Pero me genera el siguiente error en el método  **Cannot resolve method getString(java.lang.String)**.

Answer (score 1):

Según de dónde venga la librería de JSONObject es posible que tengas que hacer un `getJsonObject(String).getString()`. Pruebalo a ver y me dices si te funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que estás haciendo es intentando crear un json, entonces el método json.getString no tiene sentido, ya que eso sería para extraer datos de un json.

Para añadir objetos a un json, sería algo más parecido a esto:

```
void addJson(JsonObject json) {

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        json.put(KEY_PATIENT_ID,   "patientId");
        json.put(KEY_ReadingType, "readingType");
        json.put(KEY_DeviceMACId, "deviceMACId");
        json.put(KEY_DeviceData , "deviceData");
        json.put(KEY_DeviceType, "deviceType");

        arr.put(json);


        db.insert(TABLE_Demo , null, arr);
        db.close();
    }
```

Lo he escrito un poco de cabeza, pero pruébalo a ver si más o menos te funcionaría.

Saludos.